# Is there any way to get the vocabulary size from doc2vec model?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am using gensim `doc2vec`. I want know if there is any efficient way to know the vocabulary size from doc2vec. One crude way is to count the total number of words, but if the data is huge(1GB or more) then this won't be an efficient way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `model` is your trained Doc2Vec model, then the number of unique word tokens in the surviving vocabulary after applying your `min_count` is available from:

```
len(model.wv.vocab)
```

The number of trained document tags is available from:

```
len(model.docvecs)
```

Comment: There is no such parameter as vocab.

Comment: Of course there was – at the time of writing! And still is – just in a different place! In more-recent versions of gensim, the `vocab` object has been moved to a constituent `wv` property, and in 1.0.0, released February 2017 after this answer 1st written, a prior backward-compatibility ability to access `vocab` via `model.vocab` was removed. The answer above has been updated to match current gensim.

Comment: Welp, I deleted my comment as yours and mine were the same.

Answer (score 4):

The return data type of vocab is a dictionary. Use keys() as follows:

```
model.wv.vocab.keys()
```

This should return a list of words.

Answer (score 1):

An update for gensim version 4. You can have the vocabulary size with:

```py
vocab_len = len(model.wv)  #
```

See this [Migrating to Gensim 4.0](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes) page